# Google Cloud ListBuckets

Tags: list, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I can add a bucket , but I cant list my buckets.

Here is my code ,

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(new FileStream("gcFile.json", FileMode.Open))
                  .CreateScoped(new string[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl });
        var client = StorageClient.Create(credential);
       // var bb = client.CreateBucket("projectId", "king");
        var aa = client.ListBuckets("projectId");
```

In my service accounts I set project owner for the json file but I dont understand where is the problem

**Result View** : Children could not be evaluated

Also I tried with this ; ,StorageService.Scope.CloudPlatformReadOnly,
StorageService.Scope.DevstorageReadOnly

Framework 4.5.2

ASP.NET

Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 version=2.0.0

Google.Apis.Storage.v1  version=1.27.1.881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Authentication

The simplest way to invoke Google Cloud APIs using the client libraries is to rely on [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

### Setting up Application Default credentials using gcloud

If you already have `gcloud` installed, you can run the following command to set up application default credentials (this needs to be run only once for your device):

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

### Creating a client using Application Default Credentials and invoking APIs

After this, in your code you can instantiate the Storage client and invoke the GCS APIs as show below:

```
// Creates the storage client (authenticates using the Application Default credentials you configured earlier)
var client = StorageClient.Create();

// GCS bucket names must be globally unique
var bucketName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

// Bucket defined in Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data namespace
var bucket = client.CreateBucket(projectId, bucketName);

// List all buckets associated with a project
var buckets = client.ListBuckets(projectId);
```

### References

- Go through the [full documentation for .NET Cloud Storage Client library](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/index.html) for more examples and API documentation.
- [`CreateBucket` API](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_CreateBucket_System_String_System_String_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_CreateBucketOptions_)
- [`ListBuckets` API](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_ListBuckets_System_String_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_ListBucketsOptions_)
- [`GoogleCredential`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.3/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleCredential)

Comment: Thank you for answer I didnt know this document it is beatfll,  but I dont understand why doesn list my method ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass a GoogleCredential object as well. It is described as part of the Create documentation. The documentation for GoogleCredential is available separately - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.3/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleCredential

Comment: Thank you for the document you save my time . :)